# How to apply opacity to KML layer on top of Google Maps in the React framework?

Tags: xml, reactjs, google-maps, kml

I am confronted with 2 problems : 
1. How do I apply opacity to a KML layer on top of Google Maps using the React framework ? 
2. I have a set of 731 images that are called by the KML layer and Google exiges that these images need to be accessible via a publically accessible URL. I hosted them on AWS S3 but I have already used up the free quota and I am only testing locally on my computer. If I have hundreds or thousands of users tomorrow, how do I implement a scalable solution ?

Development environment : React v16.6.1, react-google-maps/api v1.6.0, node v10.10.0, MacBook Pro 13 inches early 2011

I tried the following things : 
1. Apply opacity using a CSS class in React. 
2. Apply opacity using a CSS ID in React.

Someone suggested modifying the opacity of images by converting them into .png first and then calling them via a KML file. But to do 731 images is fastidious.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the problem on codesandbox : 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/jolly-wilson-slhed

```
return (
<LoadScript
googleMapsApiKey="Google Maps API Key"
>
<GoogleMap
center={{ lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }}
mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
options={mapOptions}
zoom={4}>

<KmlLayer
url="https://nightskybrightness.s3.eu-west- 
3.amazonaws.com/artificialNightSkyBrightness_example.kml">
</KmlLayer>

</GoogleMap>
</LoadScript>
)
```

Expected results : KML layer with 40% opacity and a solution that is scalable for hundreds or thousands of users.

Actual results : KML with 100% opacity and I have already consumed by free quota on AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the CSS approach, in your codesandbox example, in file `styles.css` add the following css rule:

```css
.App img[src*='googleusercontent.com']{
  opacity: .4;
}
```

To implement a scalable solution, i strongly recommend you to put a CDN between your end users and amazon S3.
I personally use Cloudflare and there is a free plan. give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. At this rate I will end up recruiting you. Until then thank you very much. I am studying Cloudflare documentation to implement a CDN between users and AWS S3. The images are loading too slowly and appear a few seconds after the map is loaded. You were absolutely right.

Comment: Hello Gael, In your suggestion to use a CDN like that of Cloudflare between AWS S3 and final users, were you referring of a solution like following one ? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013791312-Fetching-object-storage-assets-through-the-Cloudflare-CDN-using-a-Cloudflare-Worker.

Comment: no. you don't need to use a Cloudflare Worker. The only requirement is to own your domain name. (domain.com) Then, using cloudflare, you can register a new DNS subdomain (image.domain.com) that point to your amazon S3 root folder. just follow the Step 1 in the link you give.

Comment: You could also host your files on github page for example. easy to push, totally free but no benefit of CDN performance. maybe it's sufficient for your needs

Comment: I have gone through Cloudflare's documentation and it mentions that a new DNS subdomain registration doesn't guarantee that the asset will be fetched. Besides I feel registering a new DNS subdomain is a delicate affair in Cloudflare. From what I understand a worker is a robust way of caching images but the worker that I coded using Cloudflare's tutorial has an error and my images are now blocked. The image loading latency is too high to stay as is. I would really prefer to implement a CDN but I am stuck with a dysfunctional worker. I can call you by phone if you have a few minutes.